# Having a button return the string value of a second spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a fragment that loads 3 spinners and a button. The list array of the second and third spinner is determined by the value of spinner 1 so when you change spinner 1, the arrays of spinners 2 and 3 change on select.

This works but I'm now struggling to retrieve the string value (and ultimately the relative numerical value) of spinner 2 on the click of the button.

In order to test my code I'm just using Toast to display the string.

The ultimate goal is to have a calculation in the background (e.g. spinner 2 multiplied by spinner 3) but when I use OnClick, the string of spinner 2 at time of onCreate is displayed.

I have tried to put a switch in OnItemSelectedListener to attribute this to both spinners but it's not worked.

Really, I want to click the button and the string of spinner 2 is displayed in toast.

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Convertor extends Fragment {

public Convertor() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.convertor_1, container, false);

    String [] values_conversion =  {"Convert1","Convert2",};
    final Spinner spinner1 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    final Spinner spinner3 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.array1_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.array2_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.array3_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.array4_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values_conversion);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setSelection(0);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()  {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>  arg0, final View view, int position,
                                   long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);
            spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
            break;
        case 1:
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            spinner3.setAdapter(adapter4);
            break;
    }
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    final String from_unit1 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(); // This gives the from string      

    final Button convert_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.convert_btn);
    convert_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), from_unit1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final Button convert_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.convert_btn);
convert_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String from_unit1 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), from_unit1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked! I can't believe that after all of the different solutions, methods and styles that I tried, simply dropping the string into the button was the key I was missing.@Deepakkaku, thank you very much. I have marked your answer as correct but my limited rep doesn't show it yet.